# External Application to use v0 endpoints

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We have several external applications that we use for plugin cards. All of them do not use v0 endpoints(See below)

[v0 endpoint setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtW1j.png)

Banno is now pushing everyone to use v0 endpoint and v0 endpoint setting can no longer be disabled.

We tried few things such as adding v0 in the baseURL, for example: https://[CONSUMER_API_ENVIRONMENT]/a/consumer/api/v0 but no luck.

Has anyone done this before and know what else we need to change other than baseURL?

Thank you.

Comment: Please review the guide we have on [Migrating to the V0 OpenID Connect Endpoints](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/guides/migratingtooidcversion0/). That'll help you understand the necessary changes.

Answer (score -1):

Please review the guide we have on [Migrating to the V0 OpenID Connect Endpoints](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/guides/migratingtooidcversion0/). That'll help you understand the necessary changes.

Comment: FYI link-only answers are not valid answers. At best, this should be a comment under the question.